# How to make a object delete itself from a list.

Tags: c#, object, self-destruction

So I have some objects in a list. I want to make my object to have a method that when called will delete itself from the list. How could I do that?

Comment: In order for that to happen, the object would have to have a reference to the list or else it would have to raise an event that the list could handle.  Without one of those two things, it would require magic.

Comment: Your object have to have a reference to the list and when some call the method you said, you have to call the `remove` method from the list with `this` as parameter.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. You should explain your problem in more detail and show what you tried to solve it so far.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this a trick question?

```
public class MyObject
{
    public void RemoveFromList(List<MyObject> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            return;

        list.Remove(this);
    }
}
```